# Same mutex name for a Windows service and exe in Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, mutex

I want to create mutex by a Windows Service and an exe with same names using CreateMutex function. If a mutex is created by the Windows Service and when the exe tries to create another mutex with the same name it succeeds without any error like ERROR_ALREADY_EXIST.

This happens only in Windows 7. But for Windows XP ERROR_ALREADY_EXIST is shown.
I am not able to make out the reason for this difference in OS and how to correct this problem.

**Sample Code**

For Service Code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>
#include<winbase.h>
using namespace std;
#define SLEEP_TIME 50000

typedef void* handle;
typedef WINADVAPI BOOL (WINAPI *PInitializeSecurityDescriptor)(PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR, DWORD);
typedef WINADVAPI BOOL (WINAPI *PSetSecurityDescriptorDacl)(PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR, BOOL, PACL, BOOL);
#define LOGFILE "D:\\result.txt"
handle temp=NULL;
static int a=65;
char muname[]={"NewMutex2"};
int errNm;
char *str;
FILE* log;

SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES  *g_pSaCms;
SERVICE_STATUS ServiceStatus; 
SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE hStatus; 

void  ServiceMain(int argc, char** argv); 
void  ControlHandler(DWORD request); 
int InitService();


bool Win32Mutex(char muname[8])
{

    HINSTANCE hAdvApi = LoadLibrary("Advapi32.DLL");
    PInitializeSecurityDescriptor pInitializeSecurityDescriptor = 0;
    PSetSecurityDescriptorDacl pSetSecurityDescriptorDacl = 0;
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD = 0;
    g_pSaCms = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES;
    if (g_pSaCms == 0)
    {
        prinerr();
        return 1;
    }
    memset(g_pSaCms,0X0, sizeof(*g_pSaCms));
    g_pSaCms->nLength = sizeof(*g_pSaCms);
    g_pSaCms->bInheritHandle = 1;

    pSD = new SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR;

    if (pSD == 0)
    {
        printerr();
            goto LABEL_CSA_ERROR;
    }

    pInitializeSecurityDescriptor = (PInitializeSecurityDescriptor)GetProcAddress(hAdvApi,"InitializeSecurityDescriptor");

    if (pInitializeSecurityDescriptor == 0)
    {
        printerr();
            goto LABEL_CSA_ERROR;
    }

    pSetSecurityDescriptorDacl = (PSetSecurityDescriptorDacl)GetProcAddress(hAdvApi, "SetSecurityDescriptorDacl");

    if (pSetSecurityDescriptorDacl == 0)
    {
            goto LABEL_CSA_ERROR;
    }

    if (!(*pInitializeSecurityDescriptor)(pSD, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION)
            || (!(*pSetSecurityDescriptorDacl)(pSD, TRUE, (PACL)0, FALSE)))
    {
            goto LABEL_CSA_ERROR;
    }

    (void)FreeLibrary(hAdvApi);
    g_pSaCms->lpSecurityDescriptor=pSD;
    goto LABEL_CSA_PASS;

LABEL_CSA_ERROR:
    (void)FreeLibrary(hAdvApi);

    if (pSD != 0)
    {
        delete pSD;
        pSD = 0;
    }

    if (g_pSaCms != 0)
    {
        delete g_pSaCms;
        g_pSaCms = 0;
    }


LABEL_CSA_PASS:
    temp=::CreateMutex(g_pSaCms,0,muname); //for icdcomm
    errNm=GetLastError();
    if (!temp)
    {
        print_err();
    }
    else
    {
        print_err();
    }
    if ((!temp) || errNm == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
    {
            if(temp)
            {
            (void)CloseHandle(temp);
            a++;
            muname[8]=a;
            Win32Mutex(muname);
            }
            else
            {
            printInf()
            }
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}



int main()
{ 
    SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY ServiceTable[2];
    ServiceTable[0].lpServiceName = "MemoryStatus";
    ServiceTable[0].lpServiceProc = (LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION)ServiceMain;

    ServiceTable[1].lpServiceName = NULL;
    ServiceTable[1].lpServiceProc = NULL;
    StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(ServiceTable);  
    return 0;
}

void ServiceMain(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    int error; 
    ServiceStatus.dwServiceType        = SERVICE_WIN32; 
    ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState       = SERVICE_START_PENDING; 
    ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted   = SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP | SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN;
    ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode      = 0; 
    ServiceStatus.dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0; 
    ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint         = 0; 
    ServiceStatus.dwWaitHint           = 0; 

    hStatus = RegisterServiceCtrlHandler(
        "MemoryStatus", 
        (LPHANDLER_FUNCTION)ControlHandler); 
    if (hStatus == (SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE)0) 
    { 
        // Registering Control Handler failed
        return; 
    }  
    // Initialize Service 
    error = InitService(); 
    if (error) 
    {
        // Initialization failed
        ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState       = SERVICE_STOPPED; 
        ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode      = -1; 
        SetServiceStatus(hStatus, &ServiceStatus); 
        return; 
    } 

    // My service
    muname[8]=a;
    Win32Mutex(muname);

    // We report the running status to SCM. 
    ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_RUNNING; 
    SetServiceStatus (hStatus, &ServiceStatus);


    // The worker loop of a service
    while (ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_RUNNING)
    {
        Sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
    }
    return;
}

// Control handler function
void ControlHandler(DWORD request) 
{ 
    switch(request) 
    { 
        case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP: 
            ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0; 
            ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState  = SERVICE_STOPPED; 
            SetServiceStatus (hStatus, &ServiceStatus);
            return; 

        case SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN: 

            ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0; 
            ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState  = SERVICE_STOPPED; 
            SetServiceStatus (hStatus, &ServiceStatus);
            return; 

        default:
            break;
    } 

    // Report current status
    SetServiceStatus (hStatus,  &ServiceStatus);

    return; 
}
```

For executable code (Code remains same, buc only change in main function)

```
int main()
{ 
    muname[8]=a;
    Win32Mutex(muname);
    Sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What difference you mean? You said that `ERROR_ALREADY_EXIST` appears in both cases (on both versions of Windows). Processes can share (named) mutex. One will create it (service in your case, as it runs before your standalone application) and another (your app) will just open it (with `CreateMutex` which will return `ERROR_ALREADY_EXIST`).

Comment: @Bojan: No, he said the code runs on Win7 ***without*** `ERROR_ALREADY_EXIST`.

Comment: Oooups, my mistake, had too many windows open, were doing multitasking so overlooked the word :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On XP:

The service, running in session zero, creates the mutex.  The application, which is also running in session zero, successfully opens a handle to the existing mutex and the last error is set to ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS to let you know what happened.

On Windows 7:

The service, running in session zero, creates the mutex.  The application, which is probably running in session one, creates a new mutex which happens to have the same name.  The two mutexes are independent.  This is possible because mutex names are scoped to the current session.

If you want the mutexes to be shared you need to create them in the Global namespace by prefixing the name with the "Global\" prefix, i.e.:

```
char muname[]={"Global\\NewMutex2"};
```

You can find more details about [session zero isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463353) here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A follow up question, how do we make a single piece of code, which works on both pre-Vista and pos-Vista. Can we just use GLOBAL\ for both the WIN OS or Do we need to protect different type of mutex with header guard.What would be your advice?

Comment: This article implies that "Global" is supported from Windows 2000 onwards: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684292%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I had the same problem, wasted a few hours with all kinds of random answers (including the microsoft official site) that suggested to change the Mutex permissions. So simple.